# ReferenceError: Class is not defined in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular 7 app. I have created a class/Model **UserRoleDto** in TypeScript as:

```
export default class UserRoleDto
{
    static userName: string;
    static userRole: string;
}
```

I am using it in a component like this:

```
import  UserRoleDto  from '../models/dto/user-role-dto';

export class SettingDataComponent implements OnInit {
   showAnalytics : boolean = false;
   constructor() {
      if(UserRoleDto.userRole === "Admin")
          this.showAnalytics = true;
  }

   ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I am getting exception at run-time, the exception is:

> ReferenceError: UserRoleDto is not defined

What am i doing wrong ? I know i am making some very silly mistake but, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Ramesh i am, i have updated the question

Comment: I am even unable to access UserRoleDto  in console @Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access properties of the class definition. What you want is to access the properties of the class **instance**. To instanciate a class, you have to use the `new` keyword:

```js
const userRole = new UserRoleDto();
```

This executes the classes `constructor` function and will create an instance of your class which is stored in the `userRole` variable. You can have multiple instances of your class. You can access *public* properties of your class and (if they are not *readonly*) you can assign values to them.

```js
userRole.userRole = 'Admin';
console.log(userRole.userRole) // prints 'Admin'
```

By default your class properties do not have any values assigned if you do not define them in your class. You can do so by

```js
export class UserRoleDto {
  userRole = 'Admin';
}
```

### Angular Dependency Injection

The Angular dependency injection is able to construct your classes intelligently without the need to instantiate them manually. If these classes are known by the DI of the corresponding module, you can inject them by defining parameters of your constructor.

I think what you want is a service (a class known by the DI) which can store data module-wide, not component wide.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserRoleService {
  userRole = 'Admin';
}
```

In your module where you also declare your component you have to define it in the providers array.

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    UserRoleService
  ]
})
```

And in your component you can then inject the service as follows

```js
export class SettingDataComponent {
  showAnalytics = false;

  constructor(private userRoleService: UserRoleService) {
    if(userRoleService.userRole === "Admin")
      this.showAnalytics = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defined your *UserRoleDto* in your *SettingDataComponent*  component. I am not sure where you get  UserRoleDto values. Don't forget to assign it before checking user role.

```
import  UserRoleDto  from '../models/dto/user-role-dto';

    export class SettingDataComponent implements OnInit {
       showAnalytics : boolean = false;
      userRoleDto: UserRoleDto;
       constructor() {
          if(this.userRoleDto.userRole === "Admin")
              this.showAnalytics = true;
      }

       ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a model so that you can tell typescript that you will have some variables in your app with that type but you are using it incorrectly.

Consider this:

```
import  UserRoleDto  from '../models/dto/user-role-dto';

export class SettingDataComponent implements OnInit {

   showAnalytics : boolean = false;
   constructor() {
      let someUserVariable: UserRoleDto;
      // In this way you can use the model to tell typescript that your variable is of type "UserRoleDto" instead of ": any".

      // Now you can assign it to an object that obeys that type and do what you want. Of course, the variables and their scope depend on your requirements.
      someUserVariable = {
       userName: 'adminUser',
       userRole: 'Admin'
      }

      if(someUserVariable.userRole === "Admin") {
       this.showAnalytics = true;
      } 
  }

   ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```